# Throwing an error in Java when an int is required

Tags: java, windows

Is there any way to throw an error if the user inputs an item that's not a int?

So for example "Enter an option:" User input "hello"
                 Error Message"hello is not a number"

Comment: Please show what have you done. This is very easy to do.

Comment: _Is there any way to throw an error_ yes there is. It's very easy. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Not to be confused with *throwing an Error*.  I think you mean printing an error. And yes there are many simple ways to do this and lots of examples on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example. But be aware: if entered value will has more than 10 digits - exception will be thrown, because int can't be more 10 digits.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Scanner for read a data (number) from input
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter an option: ");

    try {
        // Try to read number
        int option = sc.nextInt();  
        System.out.println("Option is " + option);

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        // If entered value is not number - print message
        System.out.println(sc.next() + " is not a number!");            
    }   
}
```

I recommend to read [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) or [Thinking in Java (Eckel)](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/).